# ReactJS : Only render element if array has values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I only want to render array values as elements, if the array has values and exists. In my case there is an array of colors, the user can set the current color_theme, which is represented by its index. On start there should no color_theme be chosen. My render function will try to render the current color_color_theme, but there is noch current_color_index. How can I check if there is an exsiting colorsheme before the rendering? I cannot write a return before the redering, because there are other elements, that have to be rendered.

```
 data = {
   "colorthemes" : [ ["blue","red"], ["black","grey"] ],
   "current_color_index": "", 

   ....//more 
 }


    render: function() {

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                //other stuff is rendering
            </ul>
            <ul>
                    {this.state.data.colorthemes[this.state.data.current_color_index].map(function(item, i) {
                      ....
                    }, this)}  
            </ul>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use an if condition, inside the `jsx`, something like

```
{
    condition ?
    <MyRenderElement /> :
    null
}
```

If the condition is not met, nothing will be rendered by this block of code.

**SUGGESTION**: I would suggest you to have reasonable default values rather than using such an if condition. Helps you to keep lesser control flow paths and lesser bugs.

Comment: the loop breaks, where in the loop can I place a condition? -> .map(function(item, i)...

Comment: You are using the functional programming constructs wrongly. First `map` everything and then use `filter` to remove all unwanted things.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do it in a simpler manner like:

```
{ condition && <MyRenderElement/> }
```

I would say that this makes a bit more sense for your case.